# How do I run a linear model which outputs the effect of both sexes?

Tags: r

I am running a linear model on my data to see whether Sex (a factor with 2 levels) and Age (numeric) have an impact on a variable which changes over time called 'HBDiff' (numeric).

I am using this code:

```
Model1 <- lm(HBDiff ~ SexGLM + StartingAgeGLM, data = GLMHBFixed) 
summary(Model1)
```

When i run the linear model I get this output:

```
                        Residuals:
                        Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
                        -3.0310 -0.9807  0.1384  0.9186  3.6887 

                        Coefficients:
                                       Estimate Std. Error t value    Pr(>|t|)    
                        (Intercept)     1.28003    0.23423   5.465 0.000000445 ***
                        SexGLMmale     -0.61909    0.27849  -2.223      0.0288 *  
                        StartingAgeGLM -0.02483    0.01015  -2.447      0.0165 *  
                        ---
                        Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

                        Residual standard error: 1.3 on 86 degrees of freedom
                          (144 observations deleted due to missingness)
                        Multiple R-squared:  0.1243,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.1039 
                        F-statistic: 6.103 on 2 and 86 DF,  p-value: 0.003322
```

As you can see in the output it only shows the effect of being male?

Am I reading this correct, and if not, how do I edit my code to account for both sexes?

Comment: You might want to look into the interpretation of dummy variables in regressions. Female is your baseline in this case, `SexGLMmale` therefore depicts the effect that is inherent with being male, `compared to being female`.

Comment: I added a minimal example, hope it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indicators (aka "dummies") in linear models are interpreted as *contrasts*. When you have an indicator like male=1 / female=0, the indicator shows you the difference of males vs. females. The overall effect of females is captured by the intercept. The overall effect of males is intercept + indicator.

In your case, the effect for females is 1.28 and for males 1.28 - 0.62 = 0.66.

There is an [instructive article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dummy_variable_(statistics)) (with illustration) on Wikipedia.

---

**Edit:** I added a minimal `R` example for illustration.

Generate some data with intercept 0 and slope 1 (on average):

```
# DF for person 1
df1 = data.frame(c(0.9,1.1,1.9,2.1,2.9,3.1),c(1,1,2,2,3,3),c(0,0,0,0,0,0))
colnames(df1)<-c("y","x","i")
summary(lm(y~x,data=df1))
```

This gives us as a result for person 1:

```
Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -7.252e-16  1.323e-01    0.00        1    
x            1.000e+00  6.124e-02   16.33 8.23e-05 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Now generate additional data for person 2 and combine both data to one DF. Person 2 has the same `x` as person 1, but all `y` for person 2 are `+1` compared to person 1. So person 2's function has a different intercept:

```
# DF for person 2
df2 = df1
# All y + 1
df2$y = df1$y + 1 
# He/she is indicated by i = 1
df2$i = 1 

# Combine both DFs
df=rbind(df1,df2)
df
```

Now, we run a regression and flag out person 2 (vs. person 1) by adding variable `i` (the indicator/dummy):

```
# Regression
mymod = lm(y~x+i,data=df)
summary(mymod)
```

Here is what we get:

```
Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -7.692e-16  9.428e-02     0.0        1    
x            1.000e+00  4.082e-02    24.5 1.51e-09 ***
i            1.000e+00  6.667e-02    15.0 1.13e-07 ***
```

Indicator `i` now is the difference in the intercept of person 2 (compared to person 1). We can predict the model and plot for illustration:

```
# Prediction and plot
pred = predict(mymod, newdata=df)
plot(df$x[df$i==0], pred[df$i==0],type="l",ylim=c(0,5), xlim=c(1,3), xlab = "x", ylab="y")
lines(df$x[df$i==1], pred[df$i==1], type="l", col="red")
```

Person 2 (red line) simply receives a separate "line" in our model, which is +1 *compared to* person 1 (black line). So in this model, we allow for a separate intercept for both person 1 and 2. However, both have the same slope (by definition of the model). We could also allow for separate slopes by introducing interaction terms.

[image]

R can handle factors (aka indicators/dummies) without the need for numeric encoding (factors need to be `1 = TRUE` or `0 = FALSE` if numeric). Here is how factors are treated in R:

```
# First see if "i" is numeric in the moment -> TRUE
is.numeric(df$i)

# We can treat "i" as (non-numeric) factor
df$i = as.factor(df$i)
summary(lm(y~x+i,data=df))

# We can also chenge the base level
summary(lm(y~x+relevel(i,ref="0"),data=df)) # just as before
summary(lm(y~x+relevel(i,ref="1"),data=df)) # just reversed since 1 is now the reference category
# note that intercept AND indicator change (not the marginal effect of x on y)
```

Comment: After reading this and changing my data, I am a little confused. I edited my sex column to be either 1 for female or 2 for male, and re-ran the lm. The only thing that appeared to change was the intercept from 1.28 to 1.899 and its p value changed in a way that did not affect the model outcome, but everything else stayed the same. Is this the correct model to use?

Comment: Did you assign the sex column `as.factor()`. If yes, the column is no longer interpreted as numeric and it is save to use it as "dummy" in the model (R handles this internally). If the column `is.numeric()`, assigning 1,2 is not correct. Indicators work in a multiplicative manner. They should be 0 = "no" and 1 = "yes". Try assigning `as.factor()` first and see what happens.

Comment: I had originally had it as a factor with two levels of male and female? will it make any difference if i convert them to numbers and then turn it in to a factor?

Comment: No, factor is factor regardless of what the numerical value was before. You just need to take care what the base level is. See the code I added to the answer.